# Zurb Foundation Form - Not Inline

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I am trying to get a checkbox next to it's label, and centered vertically against that label, in a Ruby on Rails form. Ideally, those would also both be in line with the Submit button.

I am using Zurb Foundation. Despite combing through the documentation, I can't get it to work. I've tried many incarnations, but here is one:

```
<div class="row collapse">
    <div class="large-4 columns"> &nbsp </div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
            <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
            <%= f.label :remember_me, 'Remember me' %>
        <div>
            <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "button" %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 columns"> &nbsp </div>
</div>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<div class="row collapse">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
        <input name="user[remember_me]" value="0" type="hidden"><input id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" value="1" type="checkbox">
        <label for="user_remember_me">Remember me</label>
        <div>
            <input class="button" name="commit" value="Sign in" type="submit">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Generated HTML also shows the load order for css files here:

```
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/assets/foundation_and_overrides.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet">    
<link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
```

3 hours spent so far trying to put a checkbox next to its label. Makes me appreciate Excel a bit more. Thanks for your help in advance.

UPDATE:

The following code has put everything on one line, but is not vertically aligning the button and the label. Removing .inline has no effect,

```
<div class="row collapse">
    <%= f.check_box :remember_me, class: 'left inline' %>
    <%= f.label :remember_me, 'Remember me', class: 'left inline' %>
    <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "button right" %>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats the generated HTML look like?

Comment: maybe take the divs away from around the label and checkbox? by default, divs display block and therefore take up 100% width of their parent.

Comment: Generated HTML added. Extra divs cleaned out to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure of the generated HTML, but I took a guess at it and put it into this CodePen which also references the Foundation framework.

**UPDATED** pen to include Foundation 4 instead.

http://codepen.io/keithwyland/pen/Cmukx

You want to remove the `<div>` elements from around the label and checkbox. And get `class="left inline"` on the checkbox `<input>`.

```
<div class="row collapse">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
          <input name="user[remember_me]" value="0" type="hidden"><input id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" value="1" type="checkbox" class="left inline">
          <label for="user_remember_me" >Remember me</label>
        <div>
            <input class="button" name="commit" value="Sign in" type="submit">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So for the ruby code, I'm thinking this (but I'm not great with ruby/rails code):

```
<div class="row collapse">
    <div class="large-4 columns"> &nbsp </div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
            <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
            <%= f.label :remember_me, 'Remember me', class: "left inline" %>
        <div>
            <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "button" %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 columns"> &nbsp </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Negative. Removing those div tags did not work. I've toyed with those divs to set width and inline status, but that did not work either. Any other ideas?

Comment: Then I'm thinking there is other CSS affecting this HTML than just the Foundation CSS. The CodePen I linked to shows the input and the label behaving exactly as you've described you want it to, and the only thing that is pulling in is Foundation CSS file.

Comment: maybe your version of foundation you're using is different than what i've pulled in there? I'm pulling in the latest I think.

Comment: You're right, I'm using Foundation 4. The classes in this case seem to be the same, though. I'm also using a pre-fabbed template with its own CSS, so you could easily be right on that as well. Any suggestions for how to force past the template's CSS? I've tried getting more specific (e.g. creating a rule for div.row.columns.inline_fix) but might not be going about it the right way. My custom CSS is currently loading first.

Comment: @steel Updated the pen and my answer. does that do it?

Comment: It doesn't. I've upgraded to Foundation 5 and changed the load order. See edits in my original question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48113/discussion-between-steel-and-keithwyland)

Answer (score 0):

you can fix the issue by adding inline to both checkbox and label and adding this to your css

```
input.inline, label.inline {
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

should solve the problem as zurb doesnt seem to account for your use case. Just keep in mind that all inline elements that have vertical align:middle will match align to each others height - it doesnt work for block level elements.

Comment: I'm also using a pre-fabbed template with its own CSS, so that could be interfering. Any suggestions for how to force past the template's CSS? I've tried getting more specific (e.g. creating a rule for div.row.columns.inline_fix) but might not be going about it the right way. My custom CSS is currently loading first.

Comment: you could try marking css styles as !important but this is not recommended.

Comment: oh your custom css should be loaded after foundation, is that the case?

Comment: I've rearranged it so that it is, but with no change. See answer for load order in generated HTML.

Comment: foundation should be the first loaded item with everything youve done placed after it, have you tried !important?

Comment: Just tried it. !important applied to the suggested rule does not seem to affect the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know it was posted 6 months ago, but I'd still like to contribute my 2c. In those cases I play with grid, so for each label-input pair I add two columns.

In first column I put a label class right, and in second one I put the input. Or, in your case, the other way around. Then pick your column ratio from 1-11 to 11-1 (depending where you want to place it) and there you go.

```
<div class="row collapse">
<div class="large-4 large-centered columns">
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        <%= f.check_box :remember_me, class: "right" %>
    </div>
    <div class="large-8 columns">
        <%= f.label :remember_me, 'Remember me' %>
    </div>        
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "button" %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, notice how I removed 2 divs containing &nbsp characters for centering the middle div, just use "large-centered" class on your content div:

```
<div class="large-4 large-centered columns">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently. I tried translating my solution to fit your issue.

```
<div class="row collapse" >
  <div>
    <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
    <%= f.label :remember_me, "Remember moi", class: "inline-right" %>
  </div>
  <div class="large-2 columns inline-right">
    <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "button" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Might need to include an offset (e.g., "small-offset-1") in there somewhere. Either on the button or the button's div.